# CRM 2015 read "dirty" value from unsaved form

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm creating new account record. The easiest way is to fill account id (vat number or something similar) and push button. Button run some javascript. Javascript read value of account id and fill the rest (call some external ws and fill account name, address and so on).

But I need to read this unsaved account id. Standard

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("accId").getValue();
```

can read only saved values.

Via debugger I found the right value, so I wrote simple function, which returns it.

Here it is:

```
function getDirtyValue(attName) {
    var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get(attlName);

    if (control != null && control.$1G_1 != null) {
        return control.$1G_1.$3V_0;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works but is there some official way to get this value?

(language correction welcome)

Comment: Do the other scripts on the account work properly ? Can you detail the steps you're taking and what goes wrong ? You shouldn't need to hack your way to attribute values.

Comment: There is nothing wrong. I need fill account. There is some mandantory fields i.e. account name, phone number etc. If these fields are not filled I cannot save accout. Now,

Comment: ...Now, I can acquire these information from webservice and fill into the form. Webservice need account ID. Account ID (vat number) is filled in  the form, but not in Xrm.Page.getAttribute("accId"). So, the function getDirtyValue() can read this required ID. So I asked if there is any "standard" way to obtain filled bud unsaved value from the form on client.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid this trick by adding a function, called when the form loads, and sets the value of the field into a global variable. You can access that variable in the on change event of that field.

Keep in mind that Microsoft does not support methods that are not present in the SDK and they might change. So if they change the property you are using, and your code is already in production, you'll end up having some problems.

Hope it helps, 
Cheers